# How to maintain position after changing div transform-origin?

Tags: javascript, css, math, transform, css-transforms

Let's say I had the following code:

```js
function rotate() {
  const elem = document.querySelector(".rect");

  elem.style.transformOrigin = "top right";
}
```

```css
.rect {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  background-color: #ddd;
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>

<button onclick="rotate()">Rotate</button>
```

You'll notice that when you click the `Rotate` button that the rectangle's `transform-origin` property changes from `center` to `top right`. As a result, the rectangle moves, because it is now rotated around a different origin.

Is it possible to have the rectangle maintain its current position, even after changing the transform origin? I am looking for a way to be able to change an element's transform origin while having it not move at all afterwards.

Basically, I'm looking for a way such that I can change the transform origin, but the div would be visually unchanged. I assume this involves some sort of translation in the `rotate` Javascript function, but I'm unsure of the exact calculations required to achieve such an effect.

Comment: This is how `transform-origin` works. `I can change the transform origin, but the div would be visually unchanged` Then why bother changing it. What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to be able to resize it properly from each corner. If you are resizing from the bottom left, the transform origin should be at the top right. It's fine, I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

```
function setRectangleOrigin(elem, newOrigin) {
  const compStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem);

  const prevML = parseInt(compStyle.marginLeft);
  const prevMT = parseInt(compStyle.marginTop);

  const r1 = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  elem.style.transformOrigin = newOrigin;
  const r2 = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  elem.style.marginLeft = prevML + (r1.x - r2.x);
  elem.style.marginTop = prevMT + (r1.y - r2.y);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
setRectangleOrigin(document.querySelector(".elem"), "top left");
```

It takes the margin left and margin top of the current rectangle and then calculates its bounding client rect. It then applies the change to the transformation origin and then immediately gets the new bounding client rect.

Then it's a matter of simply transforming the margin left via the change in position.